# adb shell and adb push for specific avd

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I have an emulator started in eclipse and also a real device connected via usb on my computer.
So in my DDMS it shows 2 devices with 2 different names ( one real and one emulator )

How can I specify on which device my ADB Commands will be executed ? ( I am missing a parameter to specify the device name )

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If there are only one device and one emulator, you can use `-d` and `-e` options to direct the commands to the real device and emulator.

Device:

```
adb -d shell
```

Emulator:

```
adb -e shell
```

Alternatively, you can use `-s <serialNumber>` option to direct the commands to a specific emulator/device instance:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
123456789b52315f    device

$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell

$ adb -s 123456789b52315f shell
```

For other options, read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much. The hint with -d and -e is exactly what I searched for.